# Query Distinct on a single Column

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a Table called SR_Audit which holds all of the updates for each ticket in our Helpdesk Ticketing system.

The table is formatted as per the below representation:

```
|-----------------|------------------|------------|------------|------------|
| SR_Audit_RecID  | SR_Service_RecID | Audit_text | Updated_By | Last_Update|
|-----------------|------------------|------------|------------|------------|
|........PK.......|.......FK.........|
```

I've constructed the below query that provides me with the appropriate output that I require in the format I want it. That is to say that I'm looking to measure how many tickets each staff member completes every day for a month.

```
select SR_audit.updated_by, CONVERT(CHAR(10),SR_Audit.Last_Update,101) as DateOfClose, count (*) as NumberClosed
from SR_Audit
where SR_Audit.Audit_Text LIKE '%to "Completed"%' AND SR_Audit.Last_Update >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) 
group by SR_audit.updated_by, CONVERT(CHAR(10),SR_Audit.Last_Update,101)
order by CONVERT(CHAR(10),SR_Audit.Last_Update,101)
```

However the query has one weakness which I'm looking to overcome.

A ticket can be reopened once its completed, which means that it can be completed again. This allows a staff member to artificially inflate their score by re-opening a ticket and completing it again, thus increasing their completed ticket count by one each time they do this.

The table has a field called SR_Service_RecID which is essentially the Ticket number. I want to put a condition in the query so that each ticket is only counted once regardless of how many times its completed, while still honouring the current where clause.

I've tried sub queries and a few other methods but haven't been able to get the results I'm after.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Courtenay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use as

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT(SR_Service_RecID)) as NumberClosed
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. And beautiful in its simplicity - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT SR_Service_RecID) as NumberClosed
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. And beautiful in its simplicity - Thanks!